# What is the difference between the values listed at Azure AD B2C > User Attributes and those in User > Profile?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Short Version**

What is the best way to return the `Company` value of a `User` in `Azure AD B2C` after they sign in?

**A)**  Add `Company` as a custom `User Attribute` and include it in the `Application Claims` of the `User Flow`?

or:

**B)**  Somehow grab the existing `Company` value from the `User Profile`?

If the answer is `B`, how can I grab that value, as it doesn't seem to be present in the `id_token` or `access_token` that is returned after a successful sign in.

**Long Version**

I was thinking to show the `Company` value of a User after they have logged in to a Node app via Azure AD B2C.

Initially, I was going to add `Company` as a `Custom Attribute` via:

`Azure AD B2C` > `User Attributes`

[image]

And then check it as an `Application Claim` at:

`Azure AD B2C` > `User Flows` > `B2C_signin_1` > `Application Claims`

[image]

But then I thought, hang on isn't the `Company` field already in the user's profile at:

`Azure AD B2C` > `Users` > `[ select user ]` > `Profile`

And indeed it is:

[image]

However, the information in the `User Profile` does not seem to be in either the `id_token` or `access_token` that is returned after a successful login:

*id_token:*
[image]

*access_token:*
[image]

**Question**

What is the best way to return the `Company` value of a `User` in `Azure AD B2C` after they sign in?

**A)**  Add `Company` as a custom `User Attribute` and include it in the `Application Claims` of the `User Flow`?

or:

**B)**  Somehow grab the existing `Company` value from the `User Profile`?

If the answer is `B`, how can I grab that value, as it doesn't seem to be present in the `id_token` or `access_token` that is returned after a successful sign in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD B2C : Not able to expose companyName as token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199484/azure-ad-b2c-not-able-to-expose-companyname-as-token)

Comment: From my understanding, I could only see two possible answers to my question `What is the best way to return the Company value of a User in Azure AD B2C after they sign in?` - which I articulated as options `A` and `B` (perhaps there are other options).  The linked question does not have an accepted answer and I don't think it provides a clear answer to my question.

Comment: Supported attributes are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes. Since company is not listed, you’d be best to use an extension attribute.

Comment: Is `extension attribute` the same as a custom `User attribute` created via `Azure AD B2C` > `User attributes` > `+ Add` button?

Comment: I am reading article about [Extension attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#extension-attributes)  and it links to several complicated concepts ([custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#provide-optional-claims-to-your-app), [schema extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=http#schema-extensions) and an ['extensions app'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/extensions-app)).

Comment: [This article about custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) states that `'the terms extension property, custom attribute, and custom claim refer to the same thing'`. But I don't understand how that can be the case as the descriptions for working with them are all so different.

Comment: [This article about choosing an extension type for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=javascript#choose-an-extension-type-for-your-application) lists 4 ways to add an extension:  1)  Extension attributes, 2)  Directory extensions, 3) Schema extensions, 4)  Open extensions.  It also states `'The 15 extension attributes are already predefined in Microsoft Graph and their property names can't be changed'`.

Comment: If I want to create a `Company` attribute for a user, and return this in their identity token after they login, how do I follow your suggestion to 'use an extension attribute'?  And, from what I am reading, it seems like the only way to update these attributes is via command line (i.e not via the Azure Portal) - can you please confirm if this is the case?